# Retornar el/los elementos que más se repitieron

Tags: javascript

Resulta y pasa que tengo que devolver el elemento que más se repite en un array. Hasta ahora lo he hecho de esta forma:

```
 function separarElementosRepetidos(array) {
  const contador = {};

  // cuenta la cantidad de veces que aparece cada elemento
  for (const elemento of array) {
    if (!contador[elemento]) {
      contador[elemento] = 1;
     
      
    } else {
      contador[elemento] = contador[elemento ] + 1;
    }
   
  }
console.log(contador)
}
const arrayOriginal = [2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 1, 6,];

separarElementosRepetidos(arrayOriginal)

// resultado: { '1': 2, '2': 2, '3': 1, '4': 2, '5': 1, '6': 1 }
```

Lo que primero he hecho es separar y enumerar el número de veces que se repite un elemento en propiedad. Lo que quiero hacer ahora es escoger el elemento que más se repite, pero en este caso quiero retornar el/los elementos que más se repitieron (si observaron bien los elementos "1,2,4", se han repetido el mismo número de veces).

Comment: Pero que esperas obtener en ese caso? Si hay 3 elementos que se repiten la mayor cantidad de veces que debería devolver esa función?

Comment: En lugar de colocar ruido en el título de la pregunta, pon el resumen de lo que necesitas hacer (o el error específico que hayas tenido) en próximas preguntas. Lee [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Primero hagamos un pequeño cambio en la función que cuenta las apariciones de cada número, retornando el objeto, en vez de hacer solamente un `console.log`:

```
 function separarElementosRepetidos(array) {
  const contador = {};

  // cuenta la cantidad de veces que aparece cada elemento
  for (const elemento of array) {
    if (!contador[elemento]) {
      contador[elemento] = 1;
     
      
    } else {
      contador[elemento] = contador[elemento ] + 1;
    }
   
  }
return contador
};
```

Ahora, la función que busca el/los máximo/s es la siguiente:

```
function obtenerMasRepetidos(separados){
    const maxValor = Math.max.apply(null,Object.values(separados));
    const masRepetidos = [];
    Object.entries(separados).forEach(s => {
        if (s[1] === maxValor) masRepetidos.push(s[0]);
    });
    
    return masRepetidos;
};
```

Utilización:

```
const arrayOriginal = [2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 1, 6,];

const separados = separarElementosRepetidos(arrayOriginal);
const masRepetidos = obtenerMasRepetidos(separados);

console.log(masRepetidos); //[ '1', '2', '4' ]
```

Aclaración: Este algoritmo tendrá bajas performances a medida que el tamaño del arreglo vaya aumentando.

Comment: Interesante lo analizare mas a fondo a ver que sale.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function separarElementosRepetidos( arr ) {
    let contador = [];
    let mayor = 1;
    for( const elemento of arr ) {
      mayor = agregar( elemento, contador, mayor );
    }  
    sale = [];
    for( let i = 0; i < contador.length; i++ ) {          
        if( contador[ i ][ 1 ] == mayor ) {
            sale.push( contador[ i ] );
        }
    }
    // sale = contador.filter( n => n[ 1 ] == mayor );
    console.log( sale );
}

function agregar( numero, array, mayor ) {  
    for( let i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
        if( array[ i ][ 0 ] == numero ) {
            array[ i ][ 1 ] = array[ i ][ 1 ] + 1; 
            if( mayor < array[ i ][ 1 ] ) {  
                mayor = array[ i ][ 1 ];
            }
            return mayor;
        } 
    }
    array.push( [ numero, 1 ] );  
    return mayor;
}

var ar = [ 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 1, 6, 9 ];
separarElementosRepetidos( ar );
```

En `separarElementosRepetidos`, creamos el array **`contador`**, donde guardaremos las letras contenidas en el `array` de entrada, y la cantidad de veces que aparece.
También creamos la variable **`mayor`**, donde guardaremos la mayor cantidad de repeticiones de cualquier letra.
El primer `for`, solo itera sobre el `array` de entrada, e instancia **`mayor`**, con lo que devuelve **`agregar`**, a la que le pasa como parámetros, la letra del `array` de entrada, **`contador`** y **`mayor`**.
El trabajo importante lo hace **`agregar`**, dentro del `for` verifica que la letra este incluida en **`contador`**, si está, le suma "1" a la cantidad de veces que aparece, y luego verifica si esta cantidad es mayor que **`mayor`**, en cuyo caso, le asigna a **`mayor`**, el valor de esta y la retorna.
Si después de que el `for` haya recorrido **`contenedor`**, no encontró la letra, agrega a **`contador`** un array conteniendo la letra y un "1".
De vuelta en **`separarElementosRepetidos`**, entramos en el segundo `for`, que recorre **`contador`**, y si encuentra una letra con una cantidad de repeticiones igual a **`mayor`**, la carga en el `array` **`sale`**, para luego devolver este.
Este último `for`, se puede reemplazar con la función `filter`, que se encuentra debajo de el.